# ejabberd block messages from users that don't stay in my friend list

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

After the installation of ejabberd, and configure to the domain. I add the mod_blocking to block users, and it works.

The problem is that when one user open a chat with another user (from the same domain), can send message. In my case, only will be valid that the user receive messages from his friend list. The user could accept request from other users, before receive texts.

Any idea of how can I configure ejabberd to this functionality? (I think that is normal, but I can't find anything similar)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

There is not default feature in XMPP to block message only from friend list. Even if you do that to avoid spam, a user can probably still spam by sending contact request with message.

Anyway, you will have to develop a custom module for that.